# Filter array of items by enum property with associated value

Tags: swift, filter, enums, associated-value

```
class MyClass: Decodable {

    let title: String?
    let type: MyClass.MyType?

    enum MyType {
        case article(data: [Article])
        case link(data: [LinkTile])
        case none
    }
}
```

I would like to filter an array of `MyClass` items, so the filtered array won't contain instances with type `.none`

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0.type != .none } // this doesn't work
```

Comment: The code you've given won't compile. Also MyClass doesn't contain any property of type `Type`.

Comment: `Type` is a keyword in Swift so probably not a good name for your enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use `==` with `enum`s with associated values.  You need to use *pattern matching*, but that needs to be done in a `switch` or `if` statement.

So, that leads to something ugly like this:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { if case .none = $0.type! { return false }; return true }
```

---

**Notes:**

1. You can't name your `enum` `Type` because it conflicts with the built-in `Type`.  Change it to something like `MyType`.
2. It is terribly confusing to use `none` as a case in a custom `enum` because it gets confused (by the humans) with `none` in an *optional*.  This is made worse by the fact that your `type` property is *optional*.  Here I have force unwrapped it, but that is dangerous of course.

   You could do:

   ```
   if case .none? = $0.type
   ```

   This would match the `none` case explicitly and treat `nil` as something you want to keep.

   To filter out `nil` and `.none`, you could use the *nil coalescing operator* `??`:

   ```
   if case .none = ($0.type ?? .none)
   ```

   I would suggest declaring `type` as `MyClass.MyType` instead of `MyClass.MyType?`.

Comment: What do you want the filter to do if `$0.type` is `nil`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a simple example of how to use enum in your context with a filter function.

```
enum Foo {

  case article(data: [Int])
  case link(data: [String])
  case `none`

  static func myfilter(array: [Foo]) -> [Foo]{
    var newArray:[Foo] = []
    for element in array {
      switch element {
      case .article(let article):
        newArray.append(.article(data: article))
      case .link(let link):
        newArray.append(.link(data: link))
      case .none:
        break
      }
    }
    return newArray
  }
}

let foo: [Foo] = [.article(data: [1,2,3]), .link(data: ["hello", "world"]), .none]

print(Foo.myfilter(array: foo))
```

I made a code which you can compile and test, you have to change the type for `Foo`, `article`and `link`.

When you want to use an enum, you have to use `switch case`.

If you absolutely want to use the filter in swift you can, but you need to implement the protocol [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) which is more complicated in this case.

For each case of your enum, you have to manage a case which use the concept of [pattern matching](https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/pattern-matching/2016/03/27/pattern-matching-1/). It is very powerful.